# How to determine if std::chrono::monotonic_clock is available?

Tags: c++, c++11, clock

C++0x N3092 states that monotonic_clock is optional:

> 20.10.5.2 Class monotonic_clock [time.clock.monotonic]
>
> 1. Objects of class monotonic_clock represent clocks for which values of time_point never decrease as physical time advances. monotonic_clock may be a synonym for system_clock if system_clock::is_monotonic is true.
> 2. **The class monotonic_clock is conditionally supported.**

Can I use SFINAE or another technique to define a traits class to determine if monotonic_clock is defined?

If not, shouldn't there be a standard macro that indicates whether monotonic_clock is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no fully-standards-conforming way to detect the presence of `std::chrono::monotonic_clock`. As was apparent from the discussions on comp.std.c++, there are some non-standard-conforming techniques involving declaring new code in namespace `std`.

Comment: Is it too late in the process to try to get a `__MONOTONIC_CLOCK_SUPPORTED` macro added to the standard? It seems to me that there should always be a standard way to test whether a conditionally supported feature is actually supported in a given implementation.  Edit:  Though, now that I found [that thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/browse_thread/thread/1a139fae83ebeb18/82c7b54911a313b0), maybe the LWG already considered it but decided not to?

Comment: This doesn't help with conditionally supported features in general, but actually `monotonic_clock` is likely to be renamed `steady_clock`, and required. See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3128.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/has-xxx-trait-def.html) and check out the thread [compile time member detection](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2003/11/56173.php).  I know that VisualStudio has a non standard keyword `__if_exists`, but AFAIK it is not available on other compilers.

Comment: I know this technique. The main problem is that monotonic::clock is not a member of a class and so the technique can not be applied (or at least not directly).